# How do I stop the interactive window from spilling my outputs into columns?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

This is a simple python code written in VScode and I used the interactive window to see my output. I realized if there is more than 23 numbers in a list, the interactive window gave me the output in a column format. is there any way to make the interactive window to give me output in a row format unless otherwise stated in the code? I would prefer to have the code in row format else I'm kinda confused on the output. Should there be any settings I should be changing in the VScode settings?

This is a picture of the interactive window output when there is 22 numbers in the list:
[22 numbers in a list, row format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyT5r.png)

And this is the interactive window output when there is 23 numbers in the list:
[23 numbers in a list, becomes a column format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVokf.png)

Comment: The result of my test in "Interactive" shows that it can be displayed in a row and wrap by itself. Could you please provide us with code that can minimize the recurrence of this problem? Please try to reinstall the -Python_ extension and reload VSCode.